# How to merge multiple mp3 files into one?

Tags: mp3, ripping, audiobook

I ripped an audiobook recently, problem is that it ripped them as separate mp3 files for each 'track'. Is there a way is just combining them all together to make one file?

Comment: Open a command prompt and then type `copy /b file1.mp3 + file2.mp3 + file3.mp3 combined.mp3`

Comment: There is a total of around 90 mp3 files, would i have to type out each file manually?

Comment: No. You could also type `copy /b *.mp3 combined.mp3`

Comment: That makes things better

Comment: But would they automatically get copied in the correct order?